# create elevation chart from kml file using php and javascript

Tags: php, javascript, google-maps-api-3, kml, elevation

I am trying to use google elevation service to create an elevation profile just like this:

https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/elevation-paths

Here is the Javascript:

```
var elevator;
var map;
var chart;
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
var polyline;

// The following path marks a general path from Mt.
// Whitney, the highest point in the continental United
// States to Badwater, Death Vallet, the lowest point.
var whitney = new google.maps.LatLng(36.578581, -118.291994);
var lonepine = new google.maps.LatLng(36.606111, -118.062778);
var owenslake = new google.maps.LatLng(36.433269, -117.950916);
var beattyjunction = new google.maps.LatLng(36.588056, -116.943056);
var panamintsprings = new google.maps.LatLng(36.339722, -117.467778);
var badwater = new google.maps.LatLng(36.23998, -116.83171);

// Load the Visualization API and the columnchart package.
google.load("visualization", "1", {packages: ["columnchart"]});

function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: lonepine,
    mapTypeId: 'terrain'
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);

  // Create an ElevationService.
  elevator = new google.maps.ElevationService();

  // Draw the path, using the Visualization API and the Elevation service.
  drawPath();
}

function drawPath() {

  // Create a new chart in the elevation_chart DIV.
  chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('elevation_chart'));

  var path = [ whitney, lonepine, owenslake, panamintsprings, beattyjunction, badwater];

  // Create a PathElevationRequest object using this array.
  // Ask for 256 samples along that path.
  var pathRequest = {
    'path': path,
    'samples': 256
  }

  // Initiate the path request.
  elevator.getElevationAlongPath(pathRequest, plotElevation);
}

// Takes an array of ElevationResult objects, draws the path on the map
// and plots the elevation profile on a Visualization API ColumnChart.
function plotElevation(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.ElevationStatus.OK) {
    elevations = results;

    // Extract the elevation samples from the returned results
    // and store them in an array of LatLngs.
    var elevationPath = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
      elevationPath.push(elevations[i].location);
    }

    // Display a polyline of the elevation path.
    var pathOptions = {
      path: elevationPath,
      strokeColor: '#0000CC',
      opacity: 0.4,
      map: map
    }
    polyline = new google.maps.Polyline(pathOptions);

    // Extract the data from which to populate the chart.
    // Because the samples are equidistant, the 'Sample'
    // column here does double duty as distance along the
    // X axis.
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Sample');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Elevation');
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
      data.addRow(['', elevations[i].elevation]);
    }

    // Draw the chart using the data within its DIV.
    document.getElementById('elevation_chart').style.display = 'block';
    chart.draw(data, {
      width: 640,
      height: 200,
      legend: 'none',
      titleY: 'Elevation (m)'
    });
  }
}
```

I have a KML file. It's contents are:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2" xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
<Document>
    <name>test.kml</name>
    <Style id="inline10">
        <LineStyle>
            <color>ff0000ff</color>
            <width>2</width>
        </LineStyle>
        <PolyStyle>
            <fill>0</fill>
        </PolyStyle>
    </Style>
    <Style id="inline00">
        <LineStyle>
            <color>ff0000ff</color>
            <width>2</width>
        </LineStyle>
        <PolyStyle>
            <fill>0</fill>
        </PolyStyle>
    </Style>
    <StyleMap id="inline">
        <Pair>
            <key>normal</key>
            <styleUrl>#inline00</styleUrl>
        </Pair>
        <Pair>
            <key>highlight</key>
            <styleUrl>#inline10</styleUrl>
        </Pair>
    </StyleMap>
    <Placemark>
        <name>4.6m run</name>
        <styleUrl>#inline</styleUrl>
        <LineString>
            <tessellate>1</tessellate>
            <coordinates>
                -118.3701083851859,33.86613514741887,0 -118.3835891373556,33.86595745112309,0 -118.3837603618944,33.86620604860725,0 -118.3860197295395,33.865106678845,0 -118.3853630075581,33.86344608835453,0 -118.392210401906,33.86235962069966,0 -118.3930072160544,33.86482879105449,0 -118.3952920372758,33.86473719683653,0 -118.3955064755973,33.86544254118038,0 -118.3978346563853,33.87119781418026,0 -118.4006823491955,33.8746256060688,0 -118.395927369356,33.8729025811578,0 -118.3929679702478,33.87284041135064,0 -118.3912963149097,33.87280457074664,0 -118.3873145130551,33.86670833356382,0 -118.3845601044409,33.86794790820593,0 -118.3840431481755,33.86710880429249,0 -118.3704571100188,33.86705385780814,0 
            </coordinates>
        </LineString>
    </Placemark>
</Document>
</kml>
```

The example on the developers blog of google creates a path from specific lat and lon values. I already have these values in the kml file under "coordinates". I'd like to create a chart that shows the elevation profile.

Also, I was able to parse through the kml file using "simplexml_load_file" to get the coordinate string:

```
-118.3701083851859,33.86613514741887,0 -118.3835891373556,33.86595745112309,0 -118.3837603618944,33.86620604860725,0 -118.3860197295395,33.865106678845,0 -118.3853630075581,33.86344608835453,0 -118.392210401906,33.86235962069966,0 -118.3930072160544,33.86482879105449,0 -118.3952920372758,33.86473719683653,0 -118.3955064755973,33.86544254118038,0 -118.3978346563853,33.87119781418026,0 -118.4006823491955,33.8746256060688,0 -118.395927369356,33.8729025811578,0 -118.3929679702478,33.87284041135064,0 -118.3912963149097,33.87280457074664,0 -118.3873145130551,33.86670833356382,0 -118.3845601044409,33.86794790820593,0 -118.3840431481755,33.86710880429249,0 -118.3704571100188,33.86705385780814,0
```

I don't know if I'm on the right path or not.

I think I need to replace this

```
var path = [ whitney, lonepine, owenslake, panamintsprings, beattyjunction, badwater];
```

With the lat,lon values from the KML.

I'm fairly new to google api. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Using geoxml3 to parse a KML file, find the first LineString in it and plot the elevation of that path:

http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmltest_elevation_linkto.html

With the route in your KML file:

http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmltest_elevation_linkto.html?filename=ShaunWright_kml.xml